# Iframe can't open php, shows Forbidden

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to open a php file in an iFrame. It works fine locally, but shows **Forbidden** in server.

Here is my code-

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="140px" height="25px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="share.php?url=test.com"></iframe>
```

I changed permission of iframe-src-file share.php to 777 but no luck. Parent files's status is: 755.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the iframe - it will show "forbidden" when you try to access the URL directly, too, doesn't it? Can you check who the file belongs to? Do you have access to Apache's error log?

Comment: it works perfect, while accessing directly.

Comment: are you using ssl (as in https)?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're using the correct URL? You are using a relative URL in the iframe file. What URL are you entering into the browser?

Comment: ok. got the issue. changed the- src="share.php?url=test.com" to take the parameter as base 64. Thanks for ur support guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
src="share.php?url=test.com"
```

having `.com` at the end, iframe thinks the whole path as a website, instead of a relative path & tries to open that. Like-

```
src="http://share.php?url=test.com"
```

Encoding the parameter value,  resolved the issue